# tag a not download when left click but download when middle click

Tags: javascript, html, download

I need to download my csv file from tag a but it doesn't work.

```
<a href="www.mywww.com/file.csv"> download </a>
```

When i click left mouse it not happen anything, Surely i try to use `target="_blank"` but it make me just open new tab , i need to pause enter for download file.

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = csv.FilePathDownload;
a.setAttribute("download", csv.FilePathDownload);
var b = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");

b.initEvent("click", true, true);
a.dispatchEvent(b);
return false;
```

I try to do a function like this but it still not download , may be at initEvent  have an event for middle click ?

But, when i use `middle click` by scroll wheel mouse it will open new tab => download file and close new tab ~Exactly i need this.
Then i find the way for make event middle click happen  .. so i can't.

Can some one help me to make event middle mouse happen same like target `onauxclick` or make a the way to download file by left click.

*Update 1*
When add element `download="file.csv"` it doesn't work to.

Thank.

ps. I do on google chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Just add download attribute

```
<a href="www.mywww.com/file.csv" download>download</a>
```